# How to upgrade or remove and install a new Android OS in Ubislate 7C+ Tablet

Tags: updates, rooting, installation, operating-system

I want to install a new Android version in my Ubislate 7C+ EDGE Tablet. It has wi-fi, 3G Network support, 10 point touch screen, inbuilt SIM card slot, 4Gb internal memory and 512Mb of RAM, and a 7in screen with 800x600 resolution support.

I don't have even the basic idea of how to start (I'm a novice), so please  start from the start. Please explain complete process step-by-step, and don't skip even the tiniest of details (connections, OS details, architecture, etc.), keywords, etc...

I am also unable to find any proper link to download android 4.2 for tablets, please refer sites or links.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I'm not quite sure what you're asking for here. "Install a new Android OS" is a pretty ambiguous term. Are you looking for the factory Android image from the manufacturer? Are you looking for a Pure "Google Android Experience"? Are you looking for a Custom ROM?

Comment: Also, whatever you're looking for, it's not going to be as simple as downloading "Android 4.2 for tablets". There is a lot of device-specific code that is proprietary and cannot be included in the Android source (drivers and the like). You'll need a build that's specifically designed for your device, and it's possible that no such build exists if the device lacks support from the manufacturer and third-parties.

Comment: dotVezz- Thanks but I don't care whether the Image is from Google or a Custom ROM. Factory image is not available as per my knowledge due to some patents, and a slow customer care & support.And yes i am looking for a pure "Google Android Experience".

Comment: eldarerathis- My device is not included in the list for rooting guides...

Comment: I found a ROM for my device at the link-http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=40693126. But I cant understand the steps of action. Please help...

Comment: The above link takes me to a site to download ROM for 7C+ , not 7C+ EDGE.. might work still..